# node modules file keeps pushing when ignored

Tags: git, github

I have a project that has had node modules folder been pushed to github, my file got over 100MB so i put the node_modules file in the gitignore file :

```
git_modules/
```

after doing git add ., then commit and push. it still tries to push node modules and fails.

Trying to remove the node modules using :

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
```

it still doesn't work after adding, committing and pushing. Then trying :

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

and it still keeps pushing node modules.
now my branch is 5 commits ahead after trying multiple ways and i'm stuck.

when doing :

```
git status
```

it just tells me my branch is 5 commits ahead.

Comment: Did you put node_modules or git_modules in your .gitignore file?

Comment: sorry node_modules, the git_modules is typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your branch is 5 commits ahead, that means you did not push (or your branch would be in sync with its remote tracking branch)

Assuming `node_modules` is not a submodule, or a nested git repositories, and that the `.gitignore` is at the same level (or above) the `node_modules/` folder (IE, not *inside* it), this should have worked.

Note that it would not have reduced the size of the repository (local or remote).
For that, you will need [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (python module).
See "[How do you install `git-filter-repo`?](https://superuser.com/a/1646987/141)", and the [`homebrew` `git-filter-repo` formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/git-filter-repo#default).

```
# on MacOS
brew install git-filter-repo

git filter-repo --invert-paths --path node_modules
git push --force
```

Comment: yes its not pushing because its not ignoring the node_modules folder making it over 100MB.
The node module is just as it is when installed and git ignore is at the same level.
im unsure why its not working either. The project is made with React. i tried that python module code you sent and it says the git filter-repo isnt a command

Comment: @BradleyOwens Even if it did ignore `node_modules`, the size of the repository (local or remote after push) would *still* be over 100MB. Rewriting the local history (and force pushing it) is the only way to trim the repository size.

Comment: @BradleyOwens And you need to [*install* `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md)

Comment: This worked! thank you heaps now i can sleep well!
Took a while to figure out how to install git-filter-repo

Comment: @BradleyOwens Great! Well done. On which OS are you, and what were the difficulties in installing `git filter-repo`?

Comment: Just the documentation I found wasn’t clear and what I tried from it didn’t work. 

Had to use home brew as I’m on Mac to download it and then used the got syntax you provided.

Comment: @BradleyOwens Thank you for your feedback.  I have edited the answer to include an installation step.